# How to define naming convention of unsecured method object in security.yml in symfony php?

Tags: symfony, symfony1, symfony-1.4, symfony-forms

Below is my `security.yml` file in which 2 methods works perfectly as an unsecured methods. But `api_slots` doesn't work as unsecured method. I don't know how I need to define method object name in `security.yml` like  `getSlotsAction` method name and I created its object like `api_slots` because for `unsecureListAction` method `api_doctors-list` is used and works perfectly as per desire.

```
security:
encoders:
    AppBundle\Entity\BaseUser:
        algorithm: bcrypt
        cost: 12

role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_USER: ROLE_USER
    ROLE_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]

providers:
    admin:
        entity:
            class: AppBundle:AdminUser
            property: email
    api:
        entity:
            class: AppBundle:BaseUser
            property: authToken

firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

    api_slots:
        pattern: ^/api/slots$
        methods: [GET]
        security: false
        anonymous: true

    api_new_register:
        pattern: ^/api/users$
        methods: [POST]
        security: false
        anonymous: true

    api_doctors_list:
        pattern: ^/api/doctors$
        methods: [GET]
        security: false
        anonymous: true

    api_area:
        pattern: ^/api
        provider: api
        user_checker: psyma.security.app_user.checker
        guard:
            authenticator: psyma.security.token_authenticator
        stateless: true
        anonymous: false

        logout:
            path: admin_logout



    main:
        pattern: ^/
        anonymous: ~

access_control:
    - { path: ^/admin/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, requires_channel: "%requires_channel%" }
    - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN, requires_channel: "%requires_channel%" }
    - { path: ^/api, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, requires_channel: "%requires_channel%" }
    - { path: ^/, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, requires_channel: "%requires_channel%" }
```

Here are my method names of above 3 unsecured method objects:

For api_doctors_list

```
/**
 * @Route("")
 * @Method("GET")
 */
public function unsecureListAction()
```

For api_new_register

```
/**
 * @param Request $request
 *
 * @return JsonResponse
 * @Route("/users")
 * @Method("POST")
 */
public function patientRegistrationAction(Request $request)
```

and for api_slots

```
/**
 * Class SlotController.
 *
 * @Route("/slots")
 */
 class SlotController extends JsonController
 {
/**
* @Route("")
* @Method("GET")
*
* @param Request $request
* 
* @return JsonResponse
*/
//@Security("has_role('ROLE_DOCTORUSER') or has_role('ROLE_PATIENTUSER') ")

public function getSlotsAction(Request $request)
```

Comment: Symfony version?  Pretty sure you are not using 1.4.  Maybe 2.8? Does console debug:router show the expected routes?  It is a bit unusual to have so many firewalls defined.  Typically you would use access control for this sort of stuff.  And when you say api_slots does not work then what does that mean?  Route not found?

Comment: api_slots object doesn't give direct access to getSlotsAction method, it still required api_key that is what i mean api_slots doesn't work. Also i didn't built it from scratch.